# -bash: PATH: command not found

Tags: bash, path, .bash-profile

I hope someone can help me solve this problem.

I am working on a mac and recently I was trying to use the export path function in .bash_profile to help me run a command from any directory in the terminal. This was my first time doing this and I did something wrong as all my commands stopped working. I managed to fix this issue using some code I found online and I also deleted the incorrect line of code I added in the .bash_profile. But now each time I open up the terminal I notice this error message.

Last login: Mon Feb 15 16:27:45 on ttys003
-bash: PATH: command not found

I am not sure what this means exactly. All my commands work fine, but I would like to fix this as I am concerned it may cause problems in the future.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: It would help if you actually post the files you've edited and commands used.

Comment: Probably `PATH =` where it should be `PATH=`. Without knowing the exact code this is the best guess.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Unfortunately I couldn't remember the exact code I used as it was a week ago.  I ended up using codementor. I had Omid Amirihosseini fix the issue for me in a zoom session and I highly recommend him! I had somehow broken the path so it did take a bit of troubleshooting. Hope this info helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Linux, Bash, the PATH variable - basics.

To display the content  of the PATH environment variable, try this:
`$ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'`

by default, before any changes this will display something similar to:

```
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/games
/usr/local/games
/snap/bin
```

... all of which are common system-wide locations (folders) containing 'executable files'.

To add a folder, e.g. `$HOME/bin/`, of your own to that list; you may place a statement in e.g. `$HOME/.bash_aliases` - *assuming that e.g. `$HOME/.bashrc` actually looks for and executes that file (which normally IS the case)*.

Use any text editor to either create `.bash_aliases` or add to it; the actual command would be
`$ nano $HOME/.bash_aliases`
*(where 'nano' is a small, easy to use and freely available text editor, `$ sudo apt install nano` would install it in a Debian based Linux)*.

type `export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` onto a new line, last in the file, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>X</kbd>, then answer Y (for yes) to save the file.

With that done, next bash shell you start will look for files to execute in your `$HOME/bin/` folder.

The files in that folder needs to be either compiled binaries or correctly formed script files, and also have the `x` flag set for `user` (you) - see `man chmod` - example use, usual settings: `$ chmod 755 $HOME/bin/filename` .